# ajax GET works, POST gives 400 error

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

`GetData(...)` method was OK, but `SetSimple(...)` method throwing error 400.

Javascript:

```
$.ajax(url,
        {
            type: action,
            timeout: 3000,
            data: { value: 123 },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                displayInfo("success: "+data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                displayInfo("error: "+errorThrown+" "+textStatus);
            }
        }
   );
```

C#:

```
[WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetData(int value);

[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
    string SetSimple(int value);
```

To run/test it I have the service opened in a browser, then my test page with the javascript in another browser.  (And dataType: "json" doesn't seem to help.)
And the fiddler response shows "The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details", but I don't see anything in the Event Logs.  Anyone see if/what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You should be transform your JavaScript object into string.

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

Then on your example

```
$.ajax (url,
    {
        type: action,
        timeout: 3000,
        data: JSON.stringify({ value: 123 }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            displayInfo("success: "+data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            displayInfo("error: "+errorThrown+" "+textStatus);
        }
    }
```

);

Comment: Try @ThiagoPXP answer and also use dataType: "json".

Comment: When I stringify() the GET and the POST fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request is setting the "data" property to { value: 123 }. You need to pass the appropriate object to the SetObject method which is CompositeType. The ajax request looks like you're using it as a utility function so just pass data as a parameter so the ajax request would be:

```
    var makeAjaxCall = function(url, action, data) {
        $.ajax(url,
            {
                type: action,
                timeout: 3000,
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    displayInfo("success: "+data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                    displayInfo("error: "+errorThrown+" "+textStatus);
                }
            }
       );
    }
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I posted the wrong C# code.  I have edited and placed the correct SetSimple(...) code.